# Table between Table Rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm attempting to place a Table between another Tables rows (notesboard is in between the trackingboard). The notesboard table being inserted between the trackingboard table's rows are related via the primary key (issue_ID). I cannot simply join and loop through the data because much of the trackingboard table's information would be extremely repetitive and I'd like to eventually use JavaScript to have an option to 'minimize' or hide the notesboard information. The only issue I'm having is to assign $rdx_ID an adaptable variable that will change as my function loops through all of trackingboards rows.

```
<html>

<body>

<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'disolDemo');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM trackingboard";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Bad Query: $sql");

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM notesboard";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2) or die("Bad Query: $sql2");

    $rdx_ID = '1';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        ?>
        <?php echo"
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>Issue ID</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Order Type</th>
            <th>Origin</th>
            <th>Destination</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>";?>
        <td><a href="edit.php?idx=<?php echo $row['issue_ID'] ?>">edit</a>
</td>
        <?php echo"
            <td>{$row['issue_ID']}</td>
            <td>{$row['customer']}</td>
            <td>{$row['orderType']}</td>
            <td>{$row['origin']}</td>
            <td>{$row['destination']}</td>
        </tr></table>
            <table><tr>
                <th>issue_ID</th>
                <th>note_ID</th>
                <th>noteDate</th>
                <th>noteTime</th>
                <th>note</th>
            </tr>";
        $query1 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM notesboard WHERE issue_ID = 
'$rdx_ID'") or die($con->error);
        while($row = $query1->fetch_assoc()){;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <?php echo"
                    <td>{$row['issue_ID']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['note_ID']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['noteDate']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['noteTime']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['note']}</td>
        </tr>"; 
        }
    }
    echo'<table>';

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you've too many connections for one thing.